# How to display different texts in a set of Enums when a condition is true or false

Tags: java, string, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

In order to validate rules to answers from users to questions, consider the following set of Enums in a Java Spring Boot application; the validation is fired whenever a user answers a question in the frontend. The validation goes through all the rules (many more than documented here):

```
public enum AngebotValidationRule implements ValidationRule<Angebot> {
   BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_PFLICHTFELD(
      FEHLERTEXT_BERATUNGSFRAGE_PFLICHTFELD,
      MessageType.ERROR,
      ((angebot, services) ->
          ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING)
              && angebot
                      .getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD)
                      .getAbsicherung()
                  == null),
      false),

  BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING(
      Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING,
      MessageType.INFO,
      ((angebot, services) ->
              (ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING)
              && angebot
                      .getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD)
                      .getAbsicherung()
                  == BeratungAbsicherung.GEWUENSCHT),
      false),

  BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH(
      Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH,
      MessageType.INFO,
      ((angebot, services) ->
          (ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOff(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING))
              && angebot
                      .getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD)
                      .getAbsicherung()
                  == BeratungAbsicherung.GEWUENSCHT),
      false),

   static class Constants {
   
    public static final String FEHLERTEXT_BERATUNGSFRAGE_PFLICHTFELD =
        "Some terrific text here!";

    public static final String HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING =
        "Some other terrific text here!";

    public static final String HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH =
        "Another terrific text here";
  }
}
```

I need to implement an if-else or switch-condition in the Enum BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING, so that - whenever a ToggleManager is on or off - a different text is displayed:

```
 BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING(
      Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING,
      MessageType.INFO,
      ((angebot, services) ->
              (ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING)
              && angebot
                      .getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD)
                      .getAbsicherung()
                  == BeratungAbsicherung.GEWUENSCHT),
      false),

BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING(
      Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH,
      MessageType.INFO,
      ((angebot, services) ->
          (ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOff(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING))
              && angebot
                      .getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD)
                      .getAbsicherung()
                  == BeratungAbsicherung.GEWUENSCHT),
      false),
```

I need to combine the Logic in these two Validation Rules with the same name, as I cannot have two Enums with the same name in a Set of Enums.

How can I achieve that?
Any hints or help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the two snippets of code? I see that you have some fields in your `enum` (a `String`, another enum, a BiFunction and a `boolean` value). Can point at the code that is responsible for generating the message? Is it a function? What's the problem with placing the condition into it?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko: The problem is that it throws error if I try to place any condition into this snippet of code. If you have any idea or solution, your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `it throws error if I try to place any condition` - than show **what you are doing** and the exact **error message** that you are getting.

Comment: You are sending the mixed signals, on one hand you want to resolve the problem, on the other hand you've marked one answer as accepted. If didn't try the accepted solution, then do it. Also you can take a look at the comments below it. If want these enum elements to be capable of **generating the text dynamically**, manipulations with the constructor will not help you. Simply because the constructor will be fired only once for each `enum` constant.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the problem is that I cannot post all the code and errors here - in a nutshell: the three validation rules posted here are in an Enum. As soon as the validation is triggered, it just executes the rule without any option- at least for my eyes - to make some sort of evaluation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You misunderstand, you **don't need to expose all your logic as is**. Keep thing simple: `MyEnum`, its constants: `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. It supports for both purposes: keeping the actual code private and make you question more focused. If each of the `enum` elements represents a rule. And you need to **combine the rules dynamically**, you have to create a method that will handle it, instead trying to change the state of enum elements. I'll be able to give you a more elaborate answer only if you provide an explanation on how want to combine these functions (if you will, then do it in a simple way)

Comment: To begin with, I'll be better to describe your functions like `(MyObject, Servise) -> {return boolean;};` or `(MyObject, Servise) -> {return String;};`. The code you've provided is not adding any information (because no one has a clue how your classes are working). Then tell whether your functions are doing their job correctly **separately**. If not, you need to explain what's wrong. If everything is fine, the question boils down to combining the values that they are producing.

Comment: You can't throw checked exceptions outside the function. If you need to make some kind of API calls that can throw a checked exception, it's not a good idea to place it inside a lambda. Before suggesting a workaround, please answer the *two questions*: **1.** What is the return type of the functions (`boolean`, `String`, a custom object)? **2.** How are you going to combine the results? `The validation goes through all the rules` How does it intended to happen? Try to explain it with words and pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING(
    ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING) ? 
    Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING 
    : Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH,
      MessageType.INFO,
      (angebot, services) -> angebot.getOrCreateBeratungsfrageByType(BeratungsfrageType.KRANKENTAGEGELD).getAbsicherung()
                  == BeratungAbsicherung.GEWUENSCHT,
    false
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use private constructor inside enum and create properties or you can use function too

```java
enum Rule{

    RULE_1(ToggleManager.context);

    String text;

    String getText(){
        // any logic
        return text;
    }

    private Rule(ToggleManager context){
        text = context.isOn ? "on" : "off";
    }
}
```

All the constants in enum are objects, like class you can do any thing using these objects
to access property `Rule.RULE_1.text`

Comment: Enum is meant to represent a set of well-defined values. Elements of `enum` are **not created dynamically**, they all will get instantiated when the `enum` will be loaded into memory. That means: **1.** you can't use instance methods and variables to while instantiating the enum elements, it will cause a compilation error; **2.** if static methods/variables inside the constructor, after the elemens have been created, subsequent changes of these static attributes will have **no impact** on them.

Comment: Therefore, what you're proposing is an equivalent of **hard-coding the text** because it will not get changed - condition will be evaluated only ones. By the way, I guess OP already has some field declared inside the `enum` and a constructor. Also, not that, constructors of `enum` are `private` by default.

Comment: @Alexander just read java documentation 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Before posting a link to a **tutorial** that you're calling **documentation**, I suggest you to get familiar with it. **JLS** clearly say: [An enum class has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants ... each enum constant c declared in the body of the declaration of E, E has an implicitly declared public static final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

Comment: A constructor will be executed **only once** for every enum constant, anything that happens inside a constructor will have **no impact** on the enum elements that are already instantiated.  If you don't understand it, I'll better for you to drill into the tutorial that you're with the documentation.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko: Ok, thanks for getting back on this issue. To illustrate, what I need, some pseudo code:  BERATUNG_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING(
      MessageType.INFO,
      ((angebot, services) ->
                    if ( ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING)) {
                    Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING,
                    } else
                      Constants.HINWEISTEXT_KRANKENTAGEGELD_CROSSSELLING_MONOLITH,
                    {

              }
              && angebot ....    this is the necessary program logic

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko: However, I cannot insert the above needed program logic into the arrow function, because it throws lots of errors. That is basically my main problem: I want to use two different constants in the validation rule, where one or the other is triggered according to the evaluation of if (ToggleContextHolder.getToggleManager().isOn(Toggle.CROSS_SELLING)). However, I am not sure where to place it and how to implement it. Any hints or help would be appreciated.